# Re Route to new tab using Route.navigate with state in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

Below is my code and I want to open this re route to a new tab, I am using state to pass an object initialState {key, value} pairs.

```
this.router.navigate(['/', 'vos', 'keyword', this.productID], {state : { ...initialState }})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this by applying Angular LocalStorage, where I stored my object data and used the object in other components.